# Text Processing - How to print line numbers after grepping a string in comma separated format in Unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I grepped a string recursively in a directory using

```
grep -rwnoH "string"  /root/Documents/ | cut -d ":" -f1,2 > input.txt
```

This gave me output as follows:
A file **input.txt** which has contents like

```
/root/Documents/file1.txt:23
/root/Documents/file1.txt:35
/root/Documents/file1.txt:56
/root/Documents/file2.txt:12
/root/Documents/file2.txt:67
/root/Documents/file2.txt:78
/root/Documents/file3.txt:2
/root/Documents/file3.txt:10
```

I want something like this:

```
/home/root/Documents/file1.txt:23,35,56
/home/root/Documents/file2.txt:12,67,78
/home/root/Documents/file3.txt:2,10
```

Comment: Will the order of numbers matter? For example, `file3.txt:10,2`?

Comment: Nope... The numbers should not be missed or repeated. Its totally cool if they are shuffled. BTW these numeric values are nothing but the line number obtained after grepping.

Comment: I have edited the note section to provide a better scenario of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `datamash` command:

```
datamash -t : -g 1 unique 2
```

Explanation: `-t` specifies the field separater, `-g 1` means group by first field, and `unique 2` will show distinct values for each group.

However, the line number will be sorted as character and 10 will go before 2.

Comment: It worked but I noticed one error in the end

_datamash: invalid input: field 2 requested, line 125 has only 1 fields_

Comment: Can you provide line 125 of input.txt?